# how to parse the following php array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to parse the following php array, somehow I am getting the result, but I couldn't get the expected output.

Array:

```
 Array (
        [0] => Array (
                [countNos] => 2
                [question_id] => 1
                [question] => Is Service Best?
                [rating] => 4
            )       
        [1] => Array (
                [countNos] => 1
                [question_id] => 2
                [question] => How much you benifitted?
                [rating] => 5
            )       
        [2] => Array (
                [countNos] => 1
                [question_id] => 2
                [question] => How much you benifitted?
                [rating] => 2               
            )
    )
```

Current code:

```
foreach ($ratings as $rating) {

    if (!in_array($rating['question_id'], $ratingArr)) {
        $ratingArr[$rating['question_id']]['question_id'] = $rating['question_id'];
        $ratingArr[$rating['question_id']]['question'] = $rating['question'];
    }

    for ($i = 5; $i >= 1; $i--) {

        if (!in_array($rating['rating'], $ratingArr[$rating['question_id']]['stars'])) {
            if ($i == $rating['rating']) {
                $ratingArr[$rating['question_id']]['stars'][$i] = $rating['countNos'];
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

This is the output I am getting:

> Notice: Undefined index: stars in C:\xampp\htdocs\mibs\module\Survey\src\Survey\Service\SurveyService.php on line 153
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mibs\module\Survey\src\Survey\Service\SurveyService.php on line 153

```
Array (
    [1] => Array (
            [question_id] => 1
            [question] => Is Service Best?
            [stars] => Array (
                    [4] => 2
                )   
        )   
    [2] => Array (
            [question_id] => 2
            [question] => How much you benifitted?
            [stars] => Array (
                    [5] => 1
                    [2] => 1
                )
        )   
)
```

But I am expecting the following output:

```
Array(
        [1] => Array(
                [question_id] => 1
                [question] => Is Service Best?
                [stars] => Array(
                        [5] => 0
                        [4] => 2
                        [3] => 0
                        [2] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                    )       
            )        
        [2] => Array(
                [question_id] => 2
                [question] => How much you benifitted?
                [stars] => Array(
                        [5] => 1
                        [4] => 0
                        [3] => 0
                        [2] => 1
                        [1] => 0
                    )        
            )        
    )
```

How can I parse this array, I am always having this type of issue, whenever I am parsing, how can I overcome this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never creating a `stars` sub-array in `$ratingArr` when you initialize a new entry, that's causing the two warnings. To get all the zero entries, you should initialize this to an array of 5 zeroes. Then you don't need a loop to add the `stars`, you can just fill in the appropriate entry directly.

And you need to use `array_key_exists`, not `in_array`, to check whether there's already an entry for `$rating['question_id']` in `$ratingArr`.

```
foreach ($ratings as $rating) {
    if (!array_key_exists($rating['question_id'], $ratingArr)) {
        $ratingArr[$rating['question_id']]['question_id'] = $rating['question_id'];
        $ratingArr[$rating['question_id']]['question'] = $rating['question'];
        $ratingArr[$rating['question_id']]['stars'] = array_fill(1, 5, 0);
    }
    $ratingArr[$rating['question_id']]['stars'][$rating['rating']] = $rating['countNos'];
}
```

Comment: Just looked at your code and asked why you used that for loop ;) Also `!in_array($rating['question_id'], $ratingArr)` does check if the question id exists as **value** in the `$ratingArr` but you use it as key, so you probably want to change that to `isset()` or just `array_key_exsits()`. And if the order of the keys in the `stars` subArray matters to OP, then you can either flip the array or use `array_fill_keys()`

Comment: Of course, what he actually meant was `array_key_exists`.

Comment: I'm going to assume for now that the order isn't significant.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through your array and check if you already have a subArray with the question id in the result array. If not, initialize the subArray. And then just add the rating.

Code:

```
<?php

    $result = [];

    foreach($array as $v){
        if(!isset($result[$v["question_id"]])){
            $result[$v["question_id"]] = [
                    "question_id" => $v["question_id"],
                    "question" => $v["question"],
                    "stars" => array_fill_keys(range(5, 1), 0),
                ];
        }

        $result[$v["question_id"]]["stars"][$v["rating"]] += $v["countNos"]

    }

?>
```